# how to applique a mask on an Alertify.js prompt

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mask, alertifyjs

Is there a way to applique a mask on a `Alertify.js` prompt ?

I need to add on a `jquery mask`a like this :

```
$('document').ready(function(){
  $('.car_number').mask('(SSS-0000');
  });
```

On an `alertify.js` prompt like this :

```
alertify.prompt( 'test', 'Insert a car number', '', function(evt, value) {
               if(value) {
                   getVal(value);
                   }
                }
               , function() {})
}
```

to get an output like :

```
PCT-5077
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Are you saying that you want the output to display in the specific format only or are you looking to also change the way that the information is entered by the user?

Comment: Yes i want that the user can enter only 3 letters and 4 numbers in this order.

Comment: It doesn't look like Alertify supports this.  The only thing that I recommend would be to manually patch the Alertify script to support the mask ability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you have acces to the DOM, you can do what ever you want:

```
function show(){
  var prompt = alertify.prompt();
  prompt.set({
   'onshow': function(){
    var input = this.elements.content.querySelector('input');
    //customize the input as you please
    $(input).mask();
    },
    'onclose':function(){
      var input = this.elements.content.querySelector('input')
      //clear the customization as this is a singleton.
      //$(input) 
    }
  })
  .show();
}
```

But remember, the default AlertifyJS prompt is a singleton, so its better to clear the customization on close.

Comment: Thanks a lot, its perfect !